# Five sequence puzzles

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

The following five sequence puzzles are quite nasty and hard to solve. 
Yet, each of them has a clear and justifiable solution.

---

> Sequence 1:
>   ?, ?, ?, B, B, C, ?, ?, F, ?, S, M, A, S, P, S, C, A, ...

---

> Sequence 2:
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, 8485, 8188, 8167, 8163, 8125, 8091, 8080, 8051, ...

---

> Sequence 3:
>   ..., 23, 4, 16, 33, 21, 6, 18, ?, ?, ?, ?, ...

---

> Sequence 4:
>   P, M, B, ?, S, C, K, E, L, H, M, H, T, ?, R, ?, ?, ?, S, H, F, B, Y, R, S, D, B, U, M, L, ...

---

> Sequence 5:
>   1, 2, 6, 7, 6, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 9, 4, 0, 1, 4, 9, 6, 7, 0, 3, 2, 0, 5, ?, ?, ?.

Comment: If you like sequence puzzles, you will like the show Only Connect. [Example from last week's episode.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAl5VXh06zQ&t=13m42s) Only Connect is known for its ruthless difficulty, but it is definitely easier than the sequences here.

Comment: Since sequence 4 has been solved last, I count it as the most difficult one of the five sequences. For that reason I assign the "correct answer" sign to Len's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sequence 4 is:

> the names of the [Nobel laureates for Literature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates_in_Literature) - the first letter of their last names listed by year since 1901.  The missing letters are shown as follows (**X+Y** meaning two names in the same year and **n/a** meaning no award for that year):
>
>  P, M, B, **M+E**, S, C, K, E, L, H, M, H, T, **n/a**, R, **v**, **G+P**, **n/a**, S, H, F, B, ...

Comment: Len: How did you happen to think of the Nobel prize?

Comment: @Gerhard - Just luck and perseverance, I guess.  I looked at a lot of lists before that.

Answer (score 12):

Sequence 1:

> Each letter in this sequence represent the starting letters of the elements of the periodic table arranged on the basis of atomic number

So,the full sequence is

> H,H,L,B,B,C,N,O,F,N,S,M,A,S,P,S,C,A,...

Comment: Nasty that Sodium is Na - that threw me.

Comment: @Floris I guess the first sequence was rather **na**sty.

Answer (score 10):

Sequences 2 and 3 can easily be done by googling. For the other three sequences, Google found nothing and I have no idea.

Sequence 2:

> Heights of the highest mountains in meters: Mount Everest 8848, K2 8611, Kangchendzonga 8586, Lhotse 8516, Makalu 8485, ... Hence the four questionmarks are 8848, 8611, 8586, 8516.

Sequence 3:

> Numbers on a Roulette wheel: 23, 4, 16, 33, 21, 6, 18, 31, 19, 8

Answer (score 9):

Sequence 5

> 3, 7 and 6. Those are the last digits of 2^100 = 1267650600228229401496703205376